# Dividing integer to get all of it's numbers and sum them

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to code a script that will take an integer that a user enters and then sum all of it's numbers. The integer must be between 1-99

Example:

> If a user enters 27
>
> Output: 9

Here's the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p number="Enter a number: "
SET sum=0

IF %number% GTR 9 (
SET /a temp=%number% %% 10
SET /a sum+=%temp%
SET /a number/=10
SET /a sum+=%number%
) ELSE (
SET /a sum+=%number%
)

echo %sum%
```

So let's say for example the number entered is 19, it should first do 19 % 10 to get the "9" and then 19 / 10 to get the 1, summing them both and getting 10. But when I actually run this code it returns 19 (in case I enter 19)

Comment: I told you already, how to make cross totals, didn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are limited to the range 1-99, the calc is direct

```
set /a "sum=%number% / 10 + %number% %% 10"
```

`%number% / 10` will return the left digit if any, 0 if `%number%` is less than 10

`%number% %% 10` will return the right digit

Just sum them

Answer (score 0):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, the value assigned to `temp` is not evaluated as you expect.

You should look for the many SO articles about `delayed expansion` and find out about `batch substrings`. This will make your task easier.

And don't use `temp` as a user-variable, however logical it may seem. `temp` is a directory pointer which tells the system where to store temporary files. Not a good idea to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
SET /p "var=Enter var (1-99) "
set /a var=%var:~0,1%+%var:~1,1% 2>nul
echo %var%
```